# Practical inductor result can I get in PCB layout

Tags: coil

I have a physical coil inductor of 1 mm width and 10 cm length.  It has 10 spiral wound turns.  Its inductance is 1.05 uH.

Can I get the same result from a PCB layout?

Comment: Welcome! You need to ask a question.

Comment: Please draw and dimension your coil.

Comment: How big a PCB??

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called PCB Toolkit.  Free on the web.  There is a page that talks about inductors.
[image]